# Multiple failureRateThreshold for a circuit breaker in resilience4j

Tags: groovy, hystrix, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I am fairly new to resilience4j. I was wondering whether it is possible to have different failureRateThreshold settings for different kinds of exception under the same circuit breaker config. I am unable to find an example for the same. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. But it's an interesting idea. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible out of the box, but you can emulate this behaviour with two different decorators: in the inner one, with one `failureRateThreshold`, you must ignore the exception expected by the outer decorator using `ignoreExceptions`. So the outer decorator will get just this exception using his own `failureRateThreshold`.